# Solutions for cookieless session in aspx web service

Tags: android, asp.net, asmx, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I have a problem that i dont know how to solve, few days ago i posted a question about using session web service with ksoap. [ksoap session web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664849/ksoap-session-web-service)        The problem was that ksoap doesn`t have cookie option so that the sessionID can be stored.  But i though about a possible solution, which will work with cookieless session, (sending the sessionID inside the url). The problem is that the session in the web service doesnt work in "cookieless mode", only with cookies which i cant use.

Another idea was to implement the same web service methods inside a aspx page  so that the cookieless session will work there, but i dont know how to call a page method.

And since i dont know how to call a page method, i thought that i should call it from my web service and just resend the returned data.

So i need a way to implement my solutions:

1) A way to make cookieless session work in a asmx web service

2) A way to call a page web method with ksoap so that the cookiless session will work there

3) Maybe a way to call an aspx page method from web service method so that i use the web service method like a "bridge" which will resend the page methods returned data.

```
    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String METHOD_NAME = "Test";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Test";   
    String URL = "http://mysite.com/WebService.asmx";

    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("s");
    pi.setValue("dddddddd");
    pi.setType(String.class);
    Request.addProperty(pi);



     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new       SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
    envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Category",new Category().getClass());
    AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

........................

And my web service method returns a list of Category objects (that is tested and working, but not if i use session).

Does anyone has a proposal??

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13907027/442580)

Basically I'd call login web service and save the `Set-Cookie` header value that came in the response. Then returning the values in subsequent calls to other web methods.

There will be two 'Set-Cookie' header keys that look something like this:

> Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=zpe44yb05a105zuz2f24aqi5; path=/;
>   HttpOnly
>
> Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=4BEC23D4FA4B34C7145550F2FE279E047ED2E16F1503896C949AC3A08DAAC932F6869D9B667A6735D6EA6419074F0F1C34BC3F08210904B2BB9E543CF4CCE6C2E70975F804E2447F60966406ADC1F015D267B0413FF4C79A252C55E904AD86BB315ED161300DF200163CFA77492D680ACCF9C763F3F61F70DA4E8261C9DB6466;
>   path=/; HttpOnly

Save them both and call subsequent "secure" webmethods with both values concatinated with a `;` between them.

The header that you include in subsequent calls should be like this:

> Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=zpe44yb05a105zuz2f24aqi5; path=/; HttpOnly;
>   .ASPXAUTH=4BEC23D4FA4B34C7145550F2FE279E047ED2E16F1503896C949AC3A08DAAC932F6869D9B667A6735D6EA6419074F0F1C34BC3F08210904B2BB9E543CF4CCE6C2E70975F804E2447F60966406ADC1F015D267B0413FF4C79A252C55E904AD86BB315ED161300DF200163CFA77492D680ACCF9C763F3F61F70DA4E8261C9DB6466;
>   path=/; HttpOnly

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer.  my problem was this:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713605/cookie-header-missing ,   the session cookie was missing, only when i called a .aspx page the reponse header had a sessionID attribute.  But i dont know how to call a web method either, so i got stuck in this problem.  What version of ksoap are u using?, cause with mine (2.4) the HeaderProperty cannot be recognised. Can u give me more detail code of how u comunicate with your web service? thank u

Comment: @markouuu My ksoap2 version is 2.6.5. However. I'm thinking it could be something server side if your `Set-Cookie` is not coming back in the header. Do you have `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]` on your web service method? You could also try fiddling with the `<sessionState cookieless="false" />` in web.config or `<forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/LogOn.aspx" ... cookieless="UseCookies"/>`.