# cookie header missing

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, ksoap2

im calling a web service with ksoap,and i want to maintain the session within the web service, im trying to set the session cookie, but from the service response i dont get the session cookie with the session ID, im doing this:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
String cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().toString();
```

and in the output there is no Cookie header, there are only these headers:

```
cache-contro=[private], content-type=[.....], server=[Microsoft-IIS/7.5], 
x-aspnet-version=[.....], x-powered-by=[ASP.NET], date=[......], 
content-length=[.....] }
```

I tested the service from a web browser and the session works, but doesnt return session cookie from an android app. Do u know wht is the problem??

Before my service method i have declared:

```
[ScriptMethod]
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

Im using `ksoap 2.6.1` library