# What sessionid/cookie information does asmx expect in the header?

Tags: android, forms-authentication, asmx, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm saving http header cookie/sessionid information when calling a login webmethod so I can send it back on subsequent webmethod calls secured by formsauthentication. I think I just need to know the proper header values to save so and send them back.

I'm calling these services from an android app using ksoap2.

When I step through the code when calling login. I see **two** `Set-Cookie` header items:

```
Set-Cookie
ASP.NET_SessionId=wblzzrtfmli4blku2dslw5iw; path=/; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie
.ASPXAUTH=8264E023428DA853BB163504C0D375D792FC631BB873F04D196E04BAEDE7F7BB39BB5C840D0CD0613A0DD58B2456F12EE21F212D93457F3D6BC2FC343C6AE1E3DD97473B055B36379D178FE6C412EFF61CFCE7FACAF43EEAE85C46B5123CB97C3AFF156F54921993F4A2B85BEE239EAFB05AFFF58FBDA3B7EBDC59B5E0A614D8CC086B5C7DF3A884DE95DBE05F6A138DB97241666870AAF9320EDD; path=/; HttpOnly
```

As I understand from the [documentation here](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/Cookies) and the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6408988/442580), I have to return the `Set-Cookie` value to the subsequent webmethods using `Cookie`. But as you can see above I'm getting **TWO Set-Cookie** header items. So which one do I send back and can I send them back as-is or do I need to strip out the `.ASPXAUTH=` portion or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the answer by sniffing out what the Set-Cookie header looked like when I called secured services from JQuery Ajax within my web application.

Basically I concatenated BOTH Set-Cookie values using a semicolon "; ".

On the login I saved it like this:

```java
StringBuilder cookieBuilder = new StringBuilder();

int intCookieValueCount = 0;
for (Object header : headerList) {
    HeaderProperty headerProperty = (HeaderProperty) header;
    String headerKey = headerProperty.getKey();
    String headerValue = headerProperty.getValue();

    if(headerKey != null){
        if(headerKey.equals("Set-Cookie"))
        {
            if(intCookieValueCount!=0){
                cookieBuilder.append("; ");
            }                   
            cookieBuilder.append(headerValue);
            intCookieValueCount++;
        }                   
    }
}

AppSettings.setSessionCookie(cookieBuilder.toString());
```

And on subsequent calls:

```java
HeaderProperty headerPropertyObj = new HeaderProperty("Cookie", AppSettings.getSessionCookie());
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
List headerList = new ArrayList();

headerList.add(headerPropertyObj);

androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerList);
```